# "Cannot generate SSPI context" Issue when connecting MS SQL Server by Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect a database by using python `pyodbc` library. And I have the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The logon attempt failed\r\n (-2146893044) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000

] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cannot generate SSPI context (-2146893044); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The lo gon attempt failed\r\n (-2146893044); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cannot generate SSPI context (-2146893044)')
```

I'm using regular login/password authentcation and it works on the same machine when connecting by MS SQL Management Studio. And it also works fine when I run the same Python script with same credentials on different machine

Comment: Is it possible that you have `Integrated Security=sspi;` or similar in your connection string in addition to having an SQL Login-based username and password?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, your suggestion helped me with the same error.